# Cannot build kurento toolbox in swift , Receiving syntax issues?

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, swift4, kurento

Hello Everyone I'm trying to inject kurento client in my swift app through cocoapods

```
pod 'KurentoToolbox'
```

successfully installed and after disabling bitcode for target project and kurento framework the build got successful, but whenever i try to import KurentoToolbox following error shows up

Then I try to Kurento Framowork in `Linked Framework` and Libraries as well as `embedded libraries`, but still facing the error Kindly see the attached the screenshots.[screen shot after adding the framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZFFx.png) , now after compiling the project it throws the following the error.[receiving this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5On4.png)

Kindly Check these screen shot which may help to better answer this question.

Comment: same problem, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add `KurentoToolbox` into your embedded libraries. Usually this solves the problem but still if it doesn't, then try to add both of them in `Linked Framework and Libraries` as well as `embedded libraries`.

Also quit your `xcode` and go to your `derived data folder` and deletes `derived data files`(also empty your trash).

Comment: Kindly check the above screen shots after adding the framework I edited the question.